# I'm Looking for dataset with Name, Father's Name, Mother's name, Age, Gender, Ethnicity, ~Birthplace

Tags: dataset, data, gan

**I am new to Data Science and I don't know where to find datasets, I Google searched, Asked ChatGPT and friends, but couldn't find what I was looking for.**

*My project is to generate new names based on the data I mentioned in above title of this question using GANs.*

I really appreciate any help regarding this. Thank you.

P.S. Since "normal" people's data might not be public but Celebrities data is public, my last option would be web scraping that data.
I also looked at Kaggle, data world and other places...

Answer (score 1):

That's the kind of sensitive information that's hard to get and hard to protect, as defined at the University of Pittsburgh as [personally identifiable information (PII)](https://www.technology.pitt.edu/help-desk/how-to-documents/guide-identifying-personally-identifiable-information-pii). I personally recommend reading and informing about the legal risk and moral responsibility of this type of data.

I not a expert but don't recommend web scrapping for GNN, these techniques use a **lot** of data, in the BIG way.

But for study activities, if you enjoy data collection, scrapping, and learning more about data processing and modeling, there is two ways:

- Some interesting responces of a [stackexchange question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/famous-people-dataset)
- [A site with historical information](http://staffordshirebmd.org.uk/marriagesearch.php#list) (*please don't abuse scrapping and read first if the site is happy with this*), i can help with an initial recipe, a start point:

1. You need make manually a few times first, and never masivally
2. First need to obtain [at this location] [3](http://staffordshirebmd.org.uk/marriagesearch.php#list) Historical records of church marriage in Staffordshire, UK. With this information, you have the name of the parents, infer the place of birth and the religion (see the century)
3. The next step is to find their children in the next n years (0-5) [in list form](http://staffordshirebmd.org.uk/bmdsearch.php) by mother's and father's last name. And you have our first people.
4. For age repeat the steps to find your children and determine their age,

but I don't understand the age variable, is it for naming tendency changes over time?

I hope I have been helpful